# How can i get a value of log4net tag at app.config?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm making a program, that using `log4net` for loging it. I added library at the project, configured `app.config` file as i need and it works great, but how can i get information from `log4net` tags for using it at my code ? For example, this is part of my app.config file:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="LogMainDebug" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:\Folder\log-mainDebug.txt" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] - [%m]%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>  

<root>
  <appender-ref ref="LogMain" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogMainDebug"/>
</root>
```

So, how can i get from it a path value "D:\Folder\log-mainDebug.txt" and use it at my code ?

Comment: is this inside app.config?

Comment: Yes, this part of xml code is inside of app.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're after is a property of `FileAppender`. You simply need to get it from the current instance of the appender:

```
var appenders = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders();
var filePath = appenders.OfType<FileAppender>().Single().File;
```

Comment: VS have a error here, it saying that "Error CS1061 'IAppender[]" does not contain a definition for "OfType" and could not find an extension method "OfType" host type "IAppender[]" as first argument (possibly missing a using Directive or an Assembly reference)."

Comment: @Ramon  Are you using a very old version of .NET? if not you should simply add a using statement for LINQ, `using System.Linq`

Comment: Looks like yes. I'm using .net 2.0 version :/

Comment: Then you can either assume it's the first appender - `var filePath = ((FileAppender)appenders[0]).File;`or use a `foreach` and check for type - `if (appender is FileAppender)`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by providing config file path as `configSource` in `log4net` config section in `app.config` as following.

```
<log4net configSource="config\log-mainDebug.txt" />
```

The limitation here is `log4net` does not accept the absolute path as `configSource`. You will have to provide a relative location of `log-mainDebug.txt` as in the above snippet.

The relative path should be relative to the location from where the application is running. So in above case you need to make sure that the folder `config` and file `log-mainDebug.txt` in that folder are available at the same location as the application.

For that you can configure post-build command for the project so that whenever you build the project the file `log-mainDebug.txt` is copied to the bin folder or whatever is the target build folder.

One such post build event command is as following.

```
xcopy /S /I /Y /R $(ProjectDir)Config  $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Config
```

this command will copy the `config` folder located outside the project folder to the build folder of the project. You need to configure this command as post build event command in the project properties windows so that it will execute every time whenever you build your project.

This should help you resolve what you want to achieve.